# In Minesweeper, how is the formula for the IOS (Index Of Speed) metric derived? (Minesweeper Online)

Tags: proof-explanation, logarithms

So I have been using [Minesweeper Online](https://minesweeper.online/) as a way to practice my Minesweeper skills. I recently found the settings, which has an Advanced Settings section where I am able to look at more statistics from my games, and one of them is IOS (Index Of Speed), which is defined as$$IOS:=\dfrac{\log(\text{3BV})}{\log(t+1)}$$<sub>(in the settings, the denominator is shown as $t-1$, however I am completely sure that this is a typo as then board completions of 1 second or under would render the IOS as a complex number, which is impossible.)</sub>

where $t$ is how much time has elapsed and 3BV is the minimum number of clicks needed to complete a board.

My question is: How is this formula derived? I sort of know what's going on because it's a ratio of minimum clicks to time, but what I am confused about is how logarithms factor into  this.

Comment: I did some testing on that site and it seems the formula stated there is "correct", in the sense that they are indeed making the calculation with $\log(t-1)$ in the denominator. If your time is $\leq 1$, it just shows _IOS: -_. Not that it matters much any way; even expert world record (26.59) is large enough for this $+1$ or $-1$ make barely more than 1% difference. Also, another site doesn't have this $\pm 1$ term at all: https://minesweepergame.com/statistics.php. Sadly, it doesn't provide a rationale behind the definition.

Comment: Note : Removed the allusion to puzzling.SE because I think this is a great fit for this site. +1

Comment: Rewriting as $(t+1)^{\text{IOS}}=3\text{BV}$ may help